# How to avoid code repetition in MySQL union query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to avoid code repetition in a MySQL union query and was wondering if there was a way to parameterize such a query. Basically, my query goes something like this (B has an if condition that depends on the date, but I am skipping that for brevity)

```
select month(A), sum(B) from T where xyz
union
select month(date_diff(A, interval 1 month)), sum(B) from T where xyz
union
select month(date_diff(A, interval 2 month)), sum(B) from T where xyz
.......
```

B and xyz are fairly long statements, and the only thing that changes is the date in each of the statements (the date impacts B, but not the condition xyz). Is there a better way of doing this that eliminates code duplication?

Comment: Have you considered prepared statements? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Unfortunately, you've obfuscated the query to the point that it's hard to speculate why you're using `UNION` at all.